# Type conversion from Any object: pattern matching vs Try()

Tags: scala, casting, type-conversion, pattern-matching, try-catch

I have an abstract Scala class with a method that receives a value whose type is `Any`. Depending on the class that extends it, the expected type of this value varies.

Let's see an example using pattern matching:

```
abstract class A {
  def operation(input: Any): Any
}

class B extends A {
  // In this class, the input parameter is expected to be a Seq[Any]
  def operation(input: Any): Any = {
    input match {
      case _: Seq[Any] => Option(input.asInstanceOf[Seq[Any]]))
      case _ => None
    }
  }
}

class C extends A {
  // In this class, the input parameter is expected to be a Map[String, Any]
  def operation(input: Any): Any = {
    input match {
      case _: Map[String, Any] => Option(input.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]))
      case _ => None
    }
  }
}
```

And this are the implementation using the `Try()` function:

```
class B extends A {
  // In this class, the input parameter is expected to be a Seq[Any]
  def operation(input: Any): Any = {
    Try(input.asInstanceOf[Seq[Any]]).toOption
  }
}

class C extends A {
  // In this class, the input parameter is expected to be a Map[String, Any]
  def operation(input: Any): Any = {
    Try(input.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]).toOption
  }
}
```

What of these options can be a best practice in Scala, and also computationally less expensive? Is there any other way to implement this idea more efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither, at least not as you've posted them. `asInstanceOf` is a code smell. Also, `Some()` did be preferred to `Option()`. However, we can achieve this without `asInstanceOf` by using pattern matching correctly:

```
def operation(input: Any): Option[Seq[Any]] = {
  input match {
    case s: Seq[Any] => Some(s)
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

As for efficiency, the `Try` approach is almost certainly slowest because it potentially requires computing a stack trace.

Also, you should try to use more specific types than `Any`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Pretty clear and concise. I have another question: Beyond the fact that `asInstanceOf` is a code smell, is it more inefficient than pattern matching? How expensive is casting an `Any` type with pattern matching?

Comment: Note that this code will only work with `Any`. If you want to use a more specific type you will need to use a nested `match` or you will get problems with type erasure.

Comment: is Som() prefered to Option() ? Never head that. or is it personal taste? I prefer Option() as if the argument is null will return None (it shouldn't be null, but java code...)

Comment: @pedrorijo91 Maybe just personal preference, but I would think, "This value must be nullable," if I saw `Option()` in code. Also, when implementing something like `Map.get()`, you really do want to return `Some(null)` if the value is null. Lastly, if something is null and I didn't realize it could be null, I think I really would want a NullPointerException to inform me of my error.

Comment: I understand your point. I personally never had a situation where I would want to keep the value null in a map. Or there is a valid value, or there isn't, so some(null) doesnt make sense in such case. But yeah, I guess is somehow subjective, so no point of discussing it